# Big traffic change for top URL

Tags: seo, google-search-console

My site was stable doing fine for last 2 years, but just 2 weeks back it's traffic dropped all of sudden by 35-50%. After 4-5 days of this I received this message(below after --- line) from GWT.

For the last week I've been trying to figure out the problem but to no avail. I've checked for malware etc but nothing found. I understand something abnormal has caused Google to send me this notification, which isn't due to any algorithmic updates. Any guess what could be the reason? In my shared account other sites have been stable.

[image]

---

## GWT Notification

http://goo.gl/oV9l9  : Big traffic change for top URL

Search results clicks for http://goo.gl/EMASI  have decreased significantly.

The number of clicks that your site receives from Google can change from day to day for a variety of factors, including automatic algorithm updates. However, if you have recently made significant changes to the content or configuration of your site, this change may be an indication that there are problems.

Recommended action

```
Check the Search Queries page in Webmaster Tools
Investigate whether the traffic change affects the whole site or just a few pages. Configuration changes are likely to affect the whole site
Some content is popular only for a short window of time. If the change in traffic affects only this kind of content this message may not be indicative of any problem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two weeks ago?  It sounds like you were hit with whatever Google launched on May 7th.   Here is a thread at WebmasterWorld from some other people that lost traffic that day:  http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4577573.htm

From the thread:

- most important pages on my site have vanished from [Google], while my less important pages continue to rank
- some kind of Google Update on May 7. So far, their spokespeople have been silent about it when asked, but it seems clear it was not some kind of "early Penguin" test.

---

The notification that you are getting in WMT is just a reaction to your loss of traffic, and a notification to you that it happened (if you hadn't already seen it in your analytics).   Those messages appear whenever you lose traffic, even from Google algorithm changes.

Comment: Aye, it may just be a cause that Google has found a better site/page to rank than yours meaning that you would drop in traffic. I get traffic change messages all the time but good ones.... `Search results clicks for mysite.com/mypage.html have increased significantly.
This message is not indicative of any problem in your site. It is simply to inform you that the number of clicks that one of your pages receives has increased recently.` So it could be that someone has increased and you have decreased which could be for many reasons such as someone else has freshened their page and out ranked you

Comment: Also worth mentioning that Pengiun v2 has just hit so you may receive more notices later on.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller I've checked it just now. The traffic dropped on 16th May and onwards. About Penguine, I've not optimized site with keywords, nor done any link building in 2 years. So it's not an issue, moreover I feel it has gained some traffic in 2 days. Contrary would have happened in case of Penguine affect. I can infer from this message that it is sent not because of algo changes but something else(I don't agree with you).

Comment: @bybe about Penguin, I've not optimized site with keywords, nor done any link building in 2 years. So it's not an issue, moreover I feel it has gained some traffic in 2 days. Contrary would have happened in case of Penguin affect. In last 3 years first time ever I've received a message like this .. "traffic reduced heavily ..". You say you regularly get it .. have you  done any settings WMT?

Comment: Folks on WebmasterWorld are also reporting that they see big rankning shifts around the 14th - 16th.  http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4569639-9-30.htm   I suggest that you join the conversation there.  This site tries to focus on questions that are going to have relevance for future visitors.  A discussion of your ranking problems in this particular time period is "too localized" for here.